# Existence of faithful state in $C^\ast$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Why does there always exist a faithful state in a separable $C^\ast$-algebra?

Comment: Well, since the unit ball in the dual space is weak$^{\ast}$-separable, there is a separating sequence of states $\omega_n$, then just sum them up $\omega = \sum 2^{-n} \omega_n$ and check that you get a faithful  state.

Comment: user16283 If @t.b.'s comment was sufficient, perhaps you can post (and accept) an answer yourself to check that you understood completely.

Answer (score 6):

Well, since the unit ball in the dual space is weak-$^*$-separable, there is a separating sequence of states $\omega_n$, then just sum them up $\omega=\sum 2^{-n}\omega_n$ and check that you get a faithful state.

Credits goes to t.b.